# Add a default user control everytime any other user control is closed in a panel

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have been trying to load a default user control every time any other user control on the same panel is closed by the user. I have a  panel named **MainContainer** and when the main form loads I am calling the following method to load that default user control named **welcome**.

```
public void AddUserControlWelcome()
{
    MainContainer.Controls.Clear();
    welcome.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    MainContainer.Controls.Add(welcome);
}
```

I have a menustrip button which calls the following method,

```
private void sellItemsToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddUserControlSellManager();
}
```

And it is defined as,

```
public void AddUserControlSellManager()
{
    MainContainer.Controls.Clear();
    sellManager.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
    MainContainer.Controls.Add(sellManager);
}
```

So, there is a button on sellManager user control which actually closes sellManager. And after that I am invoking **AddUserControlWelcome()** again from **MainContainer_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)** but the application is crashing and I don't know why.

Comment: With what exception application is crashed? If the control itself is closed, then it might be disposed and won't be displayed again, and needs to be recreated

Comment: I don't see you adding/removing handlers for ControlRemoved().  Could an infinite loop be coming into play here?  Instead of clearing, can you set Visible() to false, or use BringToFront() in some way?  Just thinking out loud.  Give us more details on the error.

Comment: It says Vshost-clr2.exe not responding. I could not get any exception as the app is crashing.
And I tried using BringToFront() but that is not how I want to solve this issue as user then will be able to load multiple controls on top of another control.

Comment: My best guess is it goes into an endless recursive loop adding/removing and firing ControlRemoved()...causing a "not responding" symptom.  One possible solution is to add the new UserControl and then iterate backwards over the Controls() collection and remove everything that is not the "current" one.  Then, in ControlRemoved(), only load the welcome screen if the Controls() collection is actually **empty**.

Comment: How are you removing the UC? Do you keep any references to it? How you you create it? Always with new? Unfortunately the relevnat code seems to be missing..

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is clear why you having this issue. `MainContainer_ControlRemoved` called not only when you remove your "sell" but "welcome" too. So, the culprit I believe is the fact that you do add control on  such event as `MainContainer_ControlRemoved`, which you shouldn't do. As good as .Net is, sometimes you have to stay away from using certain events for certain purposes , or you run into issues.

Try to do something like this. Considering that your surface can host only one control at the time

```
class SurfaceManager
{
    private Control _defaultCtrl;
    private bool _currentDefault;
    private Control _surface;

    void SurfaceManager(Control _surface, Control defaultCtrl) 
    {
        _surface = surface;
        _defaultCtrl = defaultCtrl;
        _surface = surface.Controls.Add(_defaultCtrl);
        _currentDefault = true;
    }

    public Control Add(Control ctrl)
    {
        Control c = null; // Returning removed control so you can do something else with it
        if (_surface.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            if (!_currentDefault)
                c = _surface.Controls[0];
            _surface.Controls.Clear();
        }           
        _surface = surface.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        _currentDefault = false;
        Return c;
    }

    public Control Remove()
    {
        if (_currentDefault) Return // Current is default - do nothing

        Control c = null; // Returning removed control so you can do something else with it
        if (_surface.Controls.Count > 0)
        {
            c = _surface.Controls[0];
            _surface.Controls.Clear();
        }           
        _surface = surface.Controls.Add(_defaultCtrl);
        _currentDefault = true;
        Return c;

    }

}
```

Now, in your class create instance of this manager and use `Add` or `Remove`. Remove will automatically bring on the **Welcome** screen